# how to transform function to setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I'm using setInterval for now, but wish to use setTimeout.

```
$.when(
            data['layout'] = "getMessages",
            data['limit'] = limit,
            fetchMsg(data,'[data-messages]',{"background-color":"#fff"})
        ).then(

            setInterval(function(){ 
                data['lastupdate'] = localStorage.lastupdate;
                data['layout'] = "getNewMessages",
                fetchMsg(data, '[data-body-new]',{"background-color":"#b4eeb4"});

            }, 1000)
        );
```

**//the function**

```
function fetchMsg(info, container, messageStyle){
            $.ajax({

               method: "POST",
               url: window.root+"/index.php",
               "data": info,
               error: function() {
                 alert('error');
               },  
               success: function(result) {
                  ..........
                 }
              });
```

I tried below but it doesn't work:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    data['lastupdate'] = localStorage.lastupdate;
    data['layout'] = "getNewMessages",
    fetchMsg(data, '[data-body-new]',{"background-color":"#b4eeb4"});                   
}, 1000)
```

//**the function**

```
function fetchMsg(info, container, messageStyle){
                $.ajax({

                   method: "POST",
                   url: window.root+"/index.php",
                   "data": info,
                   error: function() {
                     alert('error');
                   },  
                   success: function(result) {
                      ..........
                     },
                  complete:fetchMsg
                  });
```

Comment: Can you please describe briefly what the code is supposed to do? "[I] wish to use setTimeout" is the *what* without the *why*; a little more context will help us to help you.

Comment: Broken code isn't a good substitute for a proper explanation of what that code is expected to do

Comment: @nnnnnn i simply prefer to use setTimeout as it makes the request once after x seconds whereas setInterval makes in the interval of x seconds..and when I wanna reload the page it alerts error.

Comment: @nnnnnn, and this is for chatting system, checking for new messages at every x seconds

Answer (score 0):

I won't fix your code for you but here is a basic idea of going from an interval to a setTimeout.

Firstly, make your 'interval' equal to a variable.

`var init = setInterval(doFunc,1000);`

Later when you want to make the change:

`clearInterval(init);`

and then to set Timeout just do:

`setTimeout(doFunc);`

And thats basically it.